# Window Phone-Window Desktop Communication

Tags: database, wcf, azure, architecture, windows-phone

I want to make a client-server system. The client will be a Windows Phone app that will send its location to the server - a WPF application. What will be the best design for that I'm trying to accomplish? Consider the following:

- WCF host server on desktop (that communicates with the Windows Phone app)
- Azure bus service (not sure where to place the server)
- Database (client will write location, server will read location)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless I failed to understand the complexity of the system, why not simply send the location info from the phone into an Azure queue and read that back with your client app?

Comment: you mean, phone sende message to queue and a window desktop will create a thread the will always listen to recive message form the queue? can that even be done?

Comment: Your Windows Desktop app simply polls at regular interval the Azure queue.  Here's how to do it: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/  Another simple solution is to use Azure Mobile Services.  You'd send the location info from your phone that will be stored in a SQL Azure database.  Your desktop  app could then be connected directly to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save the information somewhere it'll probably be a good idea to have the phone app send the location information to a central location where it is stored in a database. A database on a web (or cloud) server is probably a good first option to consider.
The desktop/WPF application can then connect to and read from the database.

Unless you will only ever have a very small user base who are all going to be on the same network, communicating with an application running on a PC/desktop will be highly impractical.

Ultimately, what the "best" solution will depend on the skills, resources, experience, time and other requirements you have.